# Heyzap v10.1.1 ads not showing in iOS

Tags: heyzap

Please see the attached screenshot.

After **Heyzap v10.1.1 ( latest ) SDK** integration in **iOS**, we tried calling test suite and this is what the result

[image]

How can we make it work in iOS ?

btw, the same SDK works fine in Android

Comment: Hi, I'm a developer at Heyzap. Can you tell me what bundle ID you're using for your app?

Comment: could you share your email id ?. I will send it directly

Comment: Sure, just email support@heyzap.com, we'll be on top of it